# Get Video Title inside onLoaded() method

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I know that I can get Video Id inside onLoaded() method of YoutubePlayer StateChangeListener, like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onLoaded(String s) {

        // 's' contains Video ID
    }
```

But now just for an experiment, I want to know How could I get Video Title...

**Updated**

```
    @Override
    public void onLoaded(String s) {

        // 's' contains Video ID

        Toast.makeText(YouTubeViewActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String youtubeUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + s;
        Toast.makeText(YouTubeViewActivity.this, youtubeUrl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        try {
            if (youtubeUrl != null) {
                Toast.makeText(YouTubeViewActivity.this, "Found URL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                URL embededURL = new URL("http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=" + youtubeUrl + "&format=json");

                strTitle = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(embededURL)).getString("title");
                Toast.makeText(YouTubeViewActivity.this, strTitle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried the way suggested by @V-rundPuro-hit but I am not getting Video title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how its done

```
String video_title;

@Override
public void onLoaded(String s) {

    String youtubeUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + s;

    try {
        if (youtubeUrl != null) {
            URL embededURL = new URL("http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=" +
                youtubeUrl + "&format=json");

            video_title = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(embededURL)).getString("title");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems very easy and decent solution, that's why I have given a nice try too... but getting: Non-static method 'toString()' cannot be referenced from a static context...

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. you might have to add `compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'` in your `build.gradle`.

Comment: Tried did not resolve the issue :( added into app level's build.gradle

Comment: check your imports again. it might referencing to another `IOUtils`.

Comment: well.. if that Won't work you can get title by using typical web-service fetching algorithm. after all its API ;D

Comment: thank you very much... Yes I was referencing to another IOUtils :M... Bye

Comment: Glad i could help.

Comment: Sorry... I just given a test and found that I am not getting Video Title... that time IOUtils issue has been resolved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141631/discussion-between-v-rund-puro-hit-and-sophie).

Comment: Hi I have tested this code myself and found out it was giving `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. i solved it my adding `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.
                Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);` in `onCreate()`

Comment: Thank you so much... Tested and accepted. But still can we have some other way to resolve this...

Comment: by using `AsyncTask`, and getting title in `doInbackground`